# How come this is happening in java?

Tags: java, windows

I am using Windows and Java SE 7.

The class I created was `TestPerson`, saved it as `TestPerson.java`.

But when I try to compile it by saying `javac testperson.java` the compilation is succesfull and `TestPerson.class` is created with the exact case letters.

But, Java is case sensitive, right?

How come this is happening? If we give the wrong case, it should show an error. Is there any specific reason? However, at run time it shows an error.

Comment: no class def found error

Comment: Evidently the javac uses `File.getCanonicalPath()` which retrieves the name from disk. Or reads its content.

Comment: The `NoClassDefFoundError` is probably due to your runtime classpath being incorrect.  If the compilation is successful, the compilation is successful.

Answer (score 9):

Java is case-sensitive, but your Windows file system may not be.

Unless you have two classes with the same name (case-insensitive), it should not be a problem. Java technically allows such a thing (class Hello and class HELLO), but that would be just actively asking for trouble. Same goes for non-ASCII class names or very long class names (which again, are fine for Java, but maybe not for the filesystem that has to store the class files).

Comment: +1 I posted the same.. makes sense

Answer (score 1):

`javac` is looking for a file called `testperson.java` on the filesystem.  Since your (presumably) Windows filesystem is case-insensitive, it will return the `TestPerson.java` file when asked for `testperson.java`.  Javac doesn't inherently know this happened - it asked for a file, and received it.

What would you expect Java to do in this case?  *It* is case sensitive, it treats the two filenames differently.  But it can't really be blamed if an opaque external system treats two distinct filenames as the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with `Java` here. You are using command not a java code, So this result not due to Java case sensitivity.

Try followings in Windows

```
cd Desktop
```

and

```
cd desktop
```

Both are working similar way. In your case is similar to this